# How to Generate Table Based on User Connections

Tags: php, database, join

I'm trying to build a table from data stored on 3 separate tables that are used to determine how user accounts are related towards each other. The tables are very simple, I can explain the structure here.

---

**characters**

unique_id | name

1 Jim

2 Tim

---

**relations**

unique_id | name

1 Hated

2 Enemies

3 Friends

4 Neutral

---

**connections**

unique_id | sender | receiver | relation

1 | 1 | 1 | 1

2 | 1 | 2 | 3

3 | 2 | 1 | 2

4 | 2 | 2 | 4

sender/receiver are both integers which match a characters unique_id.

relation is a integer which match a relations unique_id.

---

So, how I want the table to work is simple enough. The table will generate a row and column for each character(users), then where the row and column intersects it will state what the relation is for the two characters.

```
x     Jim       Tim
Jim   Hated     Friends
Tim   Enemies   Neutral
```

It seems simple enough in theory but I can not figure out a method to do this without making a query for each cell in the table (looking up sender 1 receiver 1, then looking up sender 1 receiver 2) I know that would work, but that many queries seems inefficient. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you put in some sample data in the tables description above. As from the results table it's not quite obvious since "Jim is hating himself" and "Jim and Tim are both Friends and Enemies" is what I'm getting out of that ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I added some state to the tables that may help. The idea is that while Jim may see himself as Friends with Tim, Tim wouldn't see it that way and see's Jim as an Enemy.

Comment: Is Jim supposed to hate himself? Don't you just want to find out what Jim feels about Tim and vice versa? AFAICT, you only need to make 2 queries, or 4 if you want to find out what each person feels about themselves.